# C naming sub-module functions

Tags: c, naming-conventions, header-files, naming

It may be a little off-topic, and also heavily opinion-based, but I think the following problem deserves discussion:

Let say you are working on a bigger project, which consist of multiple files and multiple headers. For example you have a file(sub-module) which does save management, the other handles drawing and so on. What do you think is the best way of naming the functions inside a sub-module?

I would like something that I can see from that which file was the function declared/implemented in, which would help a lot during development and bugfixing.

My current approach:

- Prefix every function with the name of the header it was declared in, example(functions declared in header `save.h`): `save_load_savefile();`, `save_save_game();`,etc.

Do you know any other, possibly better alternatives?

Comment: "It may be a little off-topic, and also heavily opinion-based" -- you're right.

Comment: Paraphrase: "I know for a fact that the question is inappropriate for this forum, but I'm going to pose it anyway."  Seriously?

Comment: Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278185/naming-convention-for-private-modules which also askns about naming, so it may not be THAT inappropriate.

Comment: Yes - this is a very good approach.  Also `extern int save_SomeObject` and `save_SomeType`.  For a large project you need some name convention management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea would be to create a (`static`) `struct` per sub-module that has function pointers as elements. A call would look something like:

```
fileSave.load_savefile()
```

In this way you're moving a little bit in the direction of C++. You could of course also decide to use C++ in a light way, and create classes.

Comment: Interesting idea

Comment: `static struct {void (*foo_visible)(void);} FooModule ={.foo_visible=&_foo_implemented};` - looks like working.

Comment: @Sasszem Thanks for letting me know.